# Event Paint Crash When Scrolling and Draw in TopLeftHeader datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem with `EventPaint` in `datagridview`.
My `EventPaint` get crashed when my `datagridview` was scrolling, and the image show in `topleftheader` in `datagridview`.
How can i solved it? sorry i can't show the code.

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace MDACS_AOP_CFSTL
{
    public partial class MainFormActivity : Form
    {
        public string ParameterNamaKaryawan { get; private set; }
        public string ParameterSesi { get; private set; }
        public DateTime ParameterTanggal { get; private set; }
        public string headercell;
        public string headerrow;
        public string hari = "";
        Karyawan myKaryawan = new Karyawan();
        Activity myActivity = new Activity();
        ValidasiTanggal myTanggal = new ValidasiTanggal();
        ContextMenuStrip m = new ContextMenuStrip();
        Project myProject = new Project();
        DateTime tglAwal;
        DateTime tglAkhir;
        Warna coloring = new Warna();
        string headerValue = "";
        DateTime time;
        public string[,] kodeProjectToProblem = new string[10,10];

        public MainFormActivity()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///
            /// Setting property Double Buffered dari datagridview 
            /// karena propertynya ter hiden jadi harus manual
            /// 
            dataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White;
            typeof(DataGridView).InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, dataGridView1, new object[] { true });


            SetComboBox();

            SetColumn();
            SetRow();            

            dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
            {

                dataGridView1.Rows[j].Frozen = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Frozen = false;
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
            dataGridView1.AutoSize = false;
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
        {

            base.OnPaint(pevent);

        }
        private static void FreezeBand(DataGridViewBand band)
        {
            band.Frozen = true;
            DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            style.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            band.DefaultCellStyle = style;
        }
        private void dataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            //Rectangle rtHeader = this.dataGridView1.DisplayRectangle;
            //rtHeader.Height = this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight / 2;
            //this.dataGridView1.Invalidate(rtHeader);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle rtHeader = this.dataGridView1.DisplayRectangle;
            rtHeader.Height = this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight / 2;
            this.dataGridView1.Invalidate(rtHeader);
        }

        private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ///
            /// Menggambar Header Column menjadi terlihat seperti di merge cells
            ///

            Image newImage = Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + "\\SampImag.jpg", true);

            string[] monthes = (string[])myKaryawan.getKaryawan().ToArray(typeof(string));
            for (int j = 0; j < myKaryawan.CountKaryawan() * 2; )
            {


                Rectangle recBackground = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j, -1, true);
                Rectangle recImage = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j, -1, true);
                Rectangle recString = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j, -1, true);
                int w2 = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j + 1, -1, true).Width;
                recBackground.X += 1;
                recBackground.Y += 1;
                recImage.X += 1;
                recImage.Y += 1;
                recString.X += (recString.Width + w2) / 2;
                recString.Y += 1;

                recBackground.Width = recBackground.Width + w2 - 2;
                recBackground.Height = (recBackground.Height / 2 - 2) + recBackground.Height / 4;
                recImage.Width = (recImage.Width + w2) / 2 - 2;
                recImage.Height = (recImage.Height / 2 - 2) + recImage.Height / 4;
                recString.Width = (recString.Width + w2) / 2 - 2;
                recString.Height = (recString.Height / 2 - 2) + recString.Height / 4;

                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor), recBackground);
                StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
                format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(monthes[j / 2],
                    this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font,
                    new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor),
                    recString,
                    format);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, recImage);

                j += 2;
            }
            ///
            /// Initializing variable yang akan digunakan untuk menggambar
            /// Flag untuk menandakan posisi koordinat untuk looping gambar
            ///

            string awal = dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value.ToString().Substring(6).ToString();
            string akhir = dataGridView1.Rows[6].HeaderCell.Value.ToString().Substring(6).ToString();
            tglAwal = Convert.ToDateTime(awal);
            tglAkhir = Convert.ToDateTime(akhir);
            var split = new String[25];
            int countRows = myActivity.getActivityPagi(tglAwal, tglAkhir).Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            int countColumns = myActivity.getActivityPagi(tglAwal, tglAkhir).Tables[0].Columns.Count;
            Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            Font font2 = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            int[,] flag = new int[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
            int[,] flag2 = new int[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
            int[,] flag3 = new int[dataGridView1.Rows.Count, dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
            int dgRows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            int dgColumns = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
            ///
            /// Draw Background Colour dan Draw String
            /// Pertama Looping semua isi data set kedalam string array
            /// Kemudian Looping per Cell untuk menggambar Stringnya dan Fill Rectangle
            /// 

            string[,] activity = new string[myActivity.getActivityPagi(tglAwal, tglAkhir).Tables[0].Rows.Count, 6];
            for (int i = 0; i < countRows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < countColumns; j++)
                {
                    activity[i, j] = myActivity.getActivityPagi(tglAwal, tglAkhir).Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString();
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dgRows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dgColumns; j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < countRows; k++)
                    {
                        headerValue = dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value.ToString();
                        split = headerValue.Split(',');
                        time = DateTime.Parse(split[1]);
                        if (time == Convert.ToDateTime(activity[k, 5]) && dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name == activity[k, 3] + activity[k, 4])
                        {
                            Rectangle r1 = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j, i, true);
                            Rectangle r2 = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j, i, true);
                            Rectangle r3 = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j, i, true);
                            int w2 = this.dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(j, i, true).Width;
                            r1.X += 1;
                            r1.Y += flag[i, j] + 1;
                            r1.Width = 65;
                            r1.Height = 15;
                            r2.X += 1;
                            r2.Y += flag2[i, j] + 15;
                            r2.Width = 65;
                            r2.Height = 15;
                            r3.X += 1;
                            r3.Y += flag3[i, j] + 30;
                            r3.Width = 70;
                            r3.Height = 46;

                            flag[i, j] = flag[i, j] + 76;
                            flag2[i, j] = flag2[i, j] + 76;
                            flag3[i, j] = flag3[i, j] + 76;

                            if (flag3[i, j] == dataGridView1.Rows[i].MinimumHeight)
                            {
                                dataGridView1.Rows[i].MinimumHeight += 76;
                            }
                            StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
                            StringFormat format2 = new StringFormat();
                            format2.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                            format2.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
                            format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                            format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                            if (coloring.getColor(activity[k, 1]) == Color.Black)
                            {
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), r1);
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(activity[k, 0],
                                    font1,
                                    new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor),
                                    r1,
                                    format2);
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(coloring.getColor(activity[k, 1])), r2);
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(activity[k, 1],
                                    font1,
                                    new SolidBrush(Color.White),
                                    r2,
                                    format);
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(activity[k, 2],
                                    font2,
                                    new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor),
                                    r3,
                                    format2);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), r1);
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(activity[k, 0],
                                    font1,
                                    new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor),
                                    r1,
                                    format2);
                                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(coloring.getColor(activity[k, 1])), r2);
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(activity[k, 1],
                                    font1,
                                    new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor),
                                    r2,
                                    format);
                                e.Graphics.DrawString(activity[k, 2],
                                    font2,
                                    new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor),
                                    r3,
                                    format2);
                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1)
            {

                Rectangle r2 = e.CellBounds;
                r2.Y += e.CellBounds.Height / 2;
                r2.Height = e.CellBounds.Height / 2;

                e.PaintBackground(r2, true);

                e.PaintContent(r2);
                e.Handled = true;
            }

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var legendForm = new ViewLegenda();
            legendForm.Show();
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ///
            /// Membuat event paint melakukan re-draw
            /// 
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].MinimumHeight = 152;
            }
            this.dataGridView1.Invalidate();
            this.dataGridView1.Paint +=new PaintEventHandler(dataGridView1_Paint);


            //for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            //{
            //    for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            //    {
            //        dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = "";
            //    }
            //}

            ///
            /// Validasi Textbox tahun
            /// 

            if (Convert.ToInt32(txtTahun.Text) > 9999 || txtTahun.Text == "" || txtTahun.Text == "0"|| txtTahun.Text == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Masukan tahun yang benar");
            }
            else
            {
                ///
                /// Membuat Format tanggal pada Header Row
                /// Tanggalnya diambil perminggu
                /// Menentukan tanggal perminggunya ada di class validasi tanggal
                /// 

                ValidasiTanggal v = new ValidasiTanggal();
                for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        hari = "Monday,";
                    }
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        hari = "Tuesday,";
                    }
                    if (i == 2)
                    {
                        hari = "Wednesday,";
                    }
                    if (i == 3)
                    {
                        hari = "Thursday,";

                    }
                    if (i == 4)
                    {
                        hari = "Friday,";
                    }
                    if (i == 5)
                    {
                        hari = "Saturday,";
                    }
                    if (i == 6)
                    {
                        hari = "Sunday,";
                    }
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(v.FirstDateOfWeek(Convert.ToInt32(txtTahun.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinggu.SelectedItem.ToString()), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, Convert.ToInt32(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString())).Day) + i > Convert.ToInt32(myTanggal.LastDayOfMonth(int.Parse(txtTahun.Text), int.Parse(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString())).Day))
                    {
                        if (int.Parse(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString()) < 12)
                        {
                            this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = Convert.ToString(hari) + " " + Convert.ToString(int.Parse(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString()) + 1) + "/" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(v.FirstDateOfWeek(Convert.ToInt32(txtTahun.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinggu.SelectedItem.ToString()), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, Convert.ToInt32(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString())).Day) + i - Convert.ToInt32(myTanggal.LastDayOfMonth(int.Parse(txtTahun.Text), int.Parse(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString())).Day)) + "/" + txtTahun.Text;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = Convert.ToString(hari) + " " + Convert.ToString(int.Parse(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString()) - 11) + "/" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(v.FirstDateOfWeek(Convert.ToInt32(txtTahun.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinggu.SelectedItem.ToString()), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, Convert.ToInt32(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString())).Day) + i - Convert.ToInt32(myTanggal.LastDayOfMonth(int.Parse(txtTahun.Text), int.Parse(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString())).Day)) + "/" + Convert.ToString(int.Parse(txtTahun.Text)+1);

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = Convert.ToString(hari) + " " + cmbBulan.SelectedValue + "/" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(v.FirstDateOfWeek(Convert.ToInt32(txtTahun.Text), Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinggu.SelectedItem.ToString()), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, Convert.ToInt32(cmbBulan.SelectedValue.ToString())).Day) + i) + "/" + txtTahun.Text;
                    }
                }
            }


            string awal = dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value.ToString().Substring(6).ToString();
            string akhir = dataGridView1.Rows[6].HeaderCell.Value.ToString().Substring(6).ToString();
            tglAwal = Convert.ToDateTime(awal);
            tglAkhir = Convert.ToDateTime(akhir);

        }

        private void txtTahun_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
        }


//-------------------------------SET DATAGRIDVIEW--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public void SetComboBox()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            test.Add("1", "Januari");
            test.Add("2", "Februari");
            test.Add("3", "Maret");
            test.Add("4", "April");
            test.Add("5", "Mei");
            test.Add("6", "Juni");
            test.Add("7", "Juli");
            test.Add("8", "Agustus");
            test.Add("9", "September");
            test.Add("10", "Oktober");
            test.Add("11", "November");
            test.Add("12", "Desember");

            cmbBulan.DataSource = new BindingSource(test, null);
            cmbBulan.DisplayMember = "Value";
            cmbBulan.ValueMember = "Key";
            cmbMinggu.SelectedIndex = 0;
            txtTahun.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

        }

        public void SetColumn()
        {
            dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            dataGridView1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
            this.dataGridView1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;

            this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < myKaryawan.CountKaryawan(); i++)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(myKaryawan.getKaryawan()[i] + "Pagi", "07.00-12.00");
                this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(myKaryawan.getKaryawan()[i] + "Siang", "13.00-16.00");
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
            }
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 100;

            this.dataGridView1.RowCount = 8;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
            this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dataGridView1.ScrollBars = new ScrollBars();

            for (int j = 0; j < this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                this.dataGridView1.Columns[j].MinimumWidth = 70;
            }
        }
        public void SetRow()
        {
            ValidasiTanggal v = new ValidasiTanggal();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int j = 0;
                string hari = "";
                if (i == 6)
                {
                    j = 7;
                }
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    hari = "Monday,";
                }
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    hari = "Tuesday,";
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    hari = "Wednesday,";
                }
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    hari = "Thursday,";
                }
                if (i == 4)
                {
                    hari = "Friday,";
                }
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    hari = "Saturday,";
                }
                if (i == 6)
                {
                    hari = "Sunday,";
                }
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].MinimumHeight = 152;

                this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = Convert.ToString(hari) + " " + cmbBulan.SelectedValue + "/" + Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(v.FirstDateOfWeek(2014, Convert.ToInt32(cmbMinggu.SelectedItem.ToString()), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek, Convert.ToInt32(cmbBulan.SelectedValue)).Day) + i) + "/" + txtTahun.Text;
                dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 120;
            }

            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight * 2;
            this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
            this.dataGridView1.Scroll +=new ScrollEventHandler(dataGridView1_Scroll);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection c = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells;
            label1.Text = c.ToString() ;
        }


        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            this.Invalidate();
            string header = "";
            //headercell = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
            //headerrow = e.RowIndex.ToString();
            //ParameterNamaKaryawan = "a";
            var split = new string[25];
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value == null)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                header = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value.ToString();
                split = header.Split(',');
                ParameterTanggal = DateTime.Parse(split[1]);
            }

            ParameterSesi = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Substring(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Length - 4, 4);
            if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Substring(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Length - 4, 4) == "Pagi")
            {
                ParameterSesi = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Substring(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Length - 4, 4);

                ParameterNamaKaryawan = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Substring(0, dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Length - 4);
            }
            else
                if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Substring(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Length - 5, 5) == "Siang")
                {
                    ParameterSesi = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Substring(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Length - 5, 5);

                    ParameterNamaKaryawan = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Substring(0, dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Length - 5);
                }

            //ParameterTanggal = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.ToString().Substring(6));
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //this.dataGridView1.CellEnter +=new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellEnter);
            //FormAddProblem addProblem = new FormAddProblem(ParameterNamaKaryawan, ParameterSesi, ParameterTanggal);
            //addProblem.Show();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                m.Items.Clear();
                m.Items.Add("Add Activity");
                m.Items.Add("Edit Activity");
                m.Items.Add("Add Problem");
                int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
                int currentMouseOverColumn = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).ColumnIndex;
                //if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
                //{
                //    m.Items.Add((string.Format("Do something to row {0} ", currentMouseOverRow.ToString())));
                //}
                this.dataGridView1.Rows[currentMouseOverRow].Cells[currentMouseOverColumn].Selected = true;
                m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                m.ItemClicked -= new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(
    contexMenuuu_ItemClicked);
                m.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(
    contexMenuuu_ItemClicked);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This happens because when you scroll the paint event is called again, you need to invalidate when scrolling And then paint again. If you can't show code I can't help you unfortunately.

Comment: i try to invalidate in event scrolling, the paint not crashed again very thanks to you, but in `topleftheader` still painted. T_T